# How to show object properties in navigation pane of Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How can I show the object properties (for instance the description) in the Access 2007 navigation pane? Now I only see an icon plus the name of the object (table, query, ...).

Maybe this is not a real programmers question but it's a programmers tools question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the menu bar of the navigation box and choose view by details.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the quick response! Is it also possible to show them in a sort of 'gridview-like' view (column 1 = name, column 2 = description and so on) to get a quick view? I thought I can recall that from an earlier version of Access.

Comment: Or better: read them programmatically and export it to, for example, Excel or a text file?

Comment: The simplest would be to use the database documenter. You can reduce the items included to properties alone.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment, it sounds like your interest in the object `Description` properties extends beyond just viewing them in the navigation pane.  If so, you can use VBA code to retrieve those properties.

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("YourTable").Properties("Description")
```

So, if *YourTable* has a `Description` property, that code would grab it.  However, `Description` is a user-created property, meaning the property doesn't exist until you assign a value to it.  And in the case where the property hasn't yet been created, that code would trigger error 3270, 'Property not found.'  You could trap error 3270.  Once you have retrieved the `Description` you can do what you want with it ... write it to a text or Excel file, store it in a custom table, whatever.

That discussion was based on the `TableDefs` collection.  I think it should generally apply to other database object collections, such as `QueryDefs`.  However, there is something more going on which I don't understand.  I asked for the `Description` of a `QueryDef` which didn't have one, and instead of an error Access gave me a reasonable description.  I have no idea how or why that happened.  And other queries which lacked the property did in fact give me error 3270.  So all I can say is explore this if you're interested and see what you get.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I played a little with this, but for me QueryDef behaves the same, 3270 error if no description otherwise the correct description. Maybe it has something to do with versions or references. I use the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library. Maybe raise a separate question for this?

Comment: I got the same result under both Access 2003 and 2007, but only for that one query.  I still don't understand why, but it's not a concern for me.  I mentioned it only as a "heads up" in case there are other surprises with that approach.